# HTML/CSS Bootstrap Glyphicons (not all of them are showing up)

Tags: html, .net, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

**Before you mark this as a dup, please read it all:**

So I've been searching times a billion on here, and every other site, and can't find a solution that works.

I'm using .NET, and trying to use Bootstrap's Glyphicons.

A lot of them work perfectly fine, but **NOT ALL** of them are showing up.

I've literally tried every solution on here, and nothing works.

Including hosting the files myself, and loading them from the CDN.

Here's an example of one that won't load.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-queen"></span>
```

It looks like many people have had similar issues, but am I alone on this one?

Thanks, iBenji

Comment: other icons working fine??

Comment: Are you using below same versions of bootstrap and jquery plugins  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: what do you see in your browser's dev tools? can you see the class definition when selecting the element the glyphicon is added to?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-queen"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/h885aeh0/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I know this is supposed to work, but doesn't for me.  This solution is what I tried when I referred to using the CDN.  Should work, but doesn't.  Thanks again, though.  Anyone else?

Comment: Are you sure? Check the link pointing to css again I provided to you